# Use Number of Values selected in a Filter inside a Calculation Field

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I have a Date Filter with 31 days (days in a month).
I have a calculation, 
Sum(sales)/(No of days)
Based on no of days selected in the Date Filter, my calculation should change.
Eg : If 12 days are selected in filter
The Calculation should be Sum(sales)/12
If 20 days then Sum(sales)/20.
Regards

Comment: Can't you just do a count on the number of days selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
sum(Sales) / datediff('day', min(Date), max(Date))
```

Just realize that if you have missing data at the start or end of your period, say no entries at all for the first few days of the month, it will only start counting days at the very first day of data, i.e. min(Date)

For those reasons, it is often useful to pad your data to have at least one row per day, even if it most of the fields are null in the padded data row. You can use a union or left join to do that without disturbing your original data.

Comment: Thanks Alex, But this method will not help !

I just need the no of items selected from the filter, even if it is City I need this to work on that. Anything that can return No of Values selected in that filter ?

Comment: Be more specific. Post some sample data, show how your filter is defined exactly, and what value you hope to see.